# Java Trie structure

Tags: java, performance, trie

I recently have been working on a Trie in Java. I have looked at the related posts here on Code Review to try and enhance my code, but I do have some methods and constraints not present on other posts.

**Objective**

To efficiently implement a Trie data structure in Java that is fast, with low memory consumption.

---

**Constraints**

- I cannot add *any* variables to the `Node` class
- No secondary data structure, other than arrays, can be used anywhere in the code

---

**Bugs Identified**

- *Delete* method  only removes 1st node of word to be removed; Inserting "hazardous" and then inserting "hazardously", then deleting "hazardously" should remove the suffix, "ly", however delete only removes the "y" and leaves the "l" resulting, incorrectly, in "hazardousl"

---

**Goal of post**

- Suggest additional methods to implement
- Possible efficiency improvements
- Overall code improvement suggestion

---

**Node Class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
/********************************************************************************
 *  @author       Evan Bechtol (ecb120030)
 *                <h1>Project: Trie Structure</h1>
 *                <p>Program builds and implements a Trie to manipulate a dictionary and spell-checker.
 *                   Identifies the total amount of words currently present, can also delete and search
 *                   for specific words.</p>
 *  @since        2015-3-06
 *  @see         https://community.oracle.com/thread/2070706
 *  @see         en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
 *  @see         logos.cs.uic.edu/340/assignments/Solutions/Graphicalwordpopup/cvelazqu/WordPop2/
 *  @see         http://crunchify.com/a-simple-singly-linked-list-implementation-in-java/
 *  
 ********************************************************************************/

/*
 * Node class is the container class for the Trie. Each child index represents one of the 26 letters of the
 * English alphabet. Only lower-case letters are used, digits are not considered. outDegree represents the 
 * number of children that are initialized for that node.
 */
class Node {
     private boolean terminal;  //Designates character as end of word
     private int     outDegree; //Specifies character position in the word
     private Node [] children;  //Holds references to 26 potential character children

     /*
      * Constructor for root node
      */
    Node () {
        terminal  = false;
        outDegree = 0;
        children  = new Node[26];
        // All children are set to null initially, they are populated as needed
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            children[i] = null;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Set the terminal value
     */
    public void setTerminal (boolean terminal) {
        this.terminal = terminal;
    }

    /*
     * Set the outDegree of node
     */
    public void setOutDegree (int outDegree) {
        this.outDegree = outDegree;
    }

    /*
     *  If the node is not null, it returns that node
     *  else null is returned
     */
    public Node getChild (char c) {
        return children [c - 'a'];
    }

    /*
     * Returns the outDegree of the current node
     */
    public int getOutDegree () {
        return outDegree;
    }

    /*
     * Return the status of terminal variable.
     * True = node is end of word
     * False = not end of word
     */
    public boolean getTerminal () {
        return terminal;
    }

    /*
     * Attempts to insert a word into the list
     */
    public boolean insert (String word) {
        char character = word.charAt(0);
        int index = character - 'a';

        if (!childExists(index)) {
            children[index] = new Node ();
            this.setOutDegree(++outDegree);
        }

        if (word.length() > 1) {
            getChild(character).insert(word.substring(1));
        }

        else {
            getChild(character).setTerminal(true);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Recursively traverse down the Trie until we reach the last character of the word
     * and it's corresponding Node in the tree.
     */
    public boolean delete (String word) {
        char character = word.charAt(0);
        int index = character - 'a';

        if (!childExists(index)) {
            return false;
        }

        // The last character in the word does not have children
        if (getChild(character).getTerminal() && getChild(character).getOutDegree() == 0) {
                this.children[index] = null;
                this.setOutDegree(--outDegree);
            return true;
        }

        // If there are more characters in the word, we keep traversing
        if (word.length() > 1) {
            getChild(character).delete(word.substring(1));

        }

        // There are no more letters in the word and it has children
        else {
            getChild(character).setTerminal(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Determines if the word is currently in the Trie
     */
    public boolean isPresent (String word) {
        char character = word.charAt(0);
        int index = character - 'a';

        // If the child does not exist, return false
        if (!childExists(index)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (childExists(index) && word.length() > 1) {
            return getChild(character).isPresent(word.substring(1));
        }

        // We reach the end of the word 
        else if (getChild(character).getTerminal() && word.length() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Determines whether a node is populated or not
     * Returns true if it exists, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean childExists (int index) {
        return this.children[index] != null;
    }
} // End Node
```

**Trie Class**

```
/*
 * The Trie class is responsible for storing and manipulating the Trie structure. It utilizes the Node container class
 * to carry out specific functions; insertion/deletion/searching
 */
class Trie {
    private final Node root;
    private int words;  // Maintains number of words in the Trie

    /*
     * Default constructor for Trie
     */
    Trie () {
        root = new Node();
        words = 0;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the root of the Trie
     */
    public Node getRoot () {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return root;
    }

    /*
     * Set the number of words in the Trie
     */
    public void setWords (int numWords) {
        this.words = numWords;
    }

    /*
     * Returns number of words in the Trie
     */
    public int membership () {
        return words;
    }

    /*
     * Returns false if word is already present, true otherwise
     */
    public boolean insert (String word) {
         if(!root.isPresent(word) && root.insert(word.toLowerCase())) {
            this. setWords(++words);
             return true;
         }
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Returns true if present, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean isPresent (String word) {
        return root.isPresent(word);
    }

    /*
     * If word is present recursive delete is called,
     * else the word is not present for deletion
     */
    public boolean delete (String word) {
        if (root.isPresent(word) && root.delete(word.toLowerCase()))  {
            this.setWords(--words);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * Returns true if the Trie is completely empty
     */
    public boolean isEmpty () {
        return root == null;
    }

    /*
     * Recursively iterates through all nodes and all children to print words
     * that are present in the Trie
     */
   public void listAll(Node current, String word) {


       if (current.getTerminal() && current.getOutDegree() >= 1) {
           System.out.println(word);
       }


       if(current.getTerminal() && current.getOutDegree() == 0){
             System.out.println(word);
       }

       // Our child is not a word yet, we iterate though again
       else {

         // Iterate through all potential letters, looking for the next child
         for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
            if(!current.childExists(i)) {
                continue;
            }
            // Our child exists and we recursively call listAll to get the word to print
            // cast it as a char to get the character representation of the index value
            else {
                listAll(current.getChild((char)(i + 'a')), word + (char)(i + 'a'));
            }
         }
       }
   }

   /*
    * Identifies potential spelling errors in the word
    */
   public void spellCheck (String word) {
       if (!root.isPresent(word)) {
           System.out.println ("Spelling mistake " + word);
       }
   }
} // End Trie
```

**Test client**

```
 /*
 * Test client for the Trie data structure
 */
public class EVBEP2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Trie trie = new Trie ();

        // Used for accepting command line arguments
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        // Used for testing purposes
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("p2in4.txt"));

        String line = "";
        boolean done = false;

        // Loop runs as long as done != true
        while (!done) {
            line = sc.nextLine();   
            String [] tokens = line.split(" "); 


            switch (tokens[0]) {

            // Print name followed by newline
            case "N": {
                    System.out.println("Evan Clay Bechtol");
                    break;
                }

            // Add a word to the Trie
            case "A": {
                    String word = tokens[1];

                    if (trie.insert(word)) {
                        System.out.println("Word inserted");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println ("Word already exists");
                    }
                    break;  
                }

            // Delete a specific word
            case "D": {
                    String word = tokens[1];

                    if (trie.delete(word)) {
                        System.out.println("Word deleted");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Word not present");
                    }
                    break;
                }

            // Search for a specific word
            case "S": {
                    String word = tokens[1];

                    if (trie.isPresent(word)) {
                        System.out.println("Word found");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Word not found");
                    }
                    break;
                }

            // Print number of words in the Trie
            case "M": {
                    System.out.println ("Membership is " + trie.membership());
                    break;
                }

            /*
             *  Check the space separated sequence of words up to the end of the line
             *  for presence in the Trie and list any that are not present, one per line, 
             *  each preceded by the phrase "Spelling mistake".
             *  Each line can be up to 200 characters long.
             */
            case "C": {
                // Get the number of usable indexes (word not used for anything here)
                int index = 0;
                for (@SuppressWarnings("unused") String word : tokens) {
                    index++;
                }

                // Now iterate through usable indexes and check for spelling errors
                int i = 1;
                while (i < index) {
                    trie.spellCheck(tokens[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            }

            // Print the elements in the Trie sorted alphabetically, one word per line.
            case "L": {
                trie.listAll(trie.getRoot(), "");
                break;
            }

            // End of data file, print newline and exit
            case "E": {
                    System.out.println();
                    done = true;    // Break the loop, end the program
                    break;
                }
            } // End switch
        } // End while
        sc.close();
    } // End main
} // End EVBEP2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `Node`'s constructor you can omit the call to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    children[i] = null;
}
```

because by initializing the `children` array with `children  = new Node[26];` the items in the array are `null` anyway.

I find it odd that you restrict the `children` array to `26` elements, but I see that you want to store the alphabet in there. But what about `Unicode` characters ?.

If it is allowed to add an overloaded constructor passing in a different upper bound of the `children` array, you should consider to to so.

```
Node (int numberOfChildren) {
    terminal  = false;
    outDegree = 0;
    children  = new Node[numberOfChildren];
}
```

which could be called from the parameterless constructor like

```
Node () {
    this(26);
}
```

Also the javadoc / class summary is misleading. English is not my first language, but I assume in the english alphabet ther are only `26` letters.

---

You should do some validation on the passed in parameters. E.g. in the `insert()` method, if one passes `null` or an empty string, either a NullPointerException or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` would be thrown.

---

If a method returns a boolean, one would expect that there are cases where the method will return `false` too. A method which only ever returns `true` like the `insert()` method does not need a return value and could be `void`.

---

If you need a value which is retrieved by calling a method like `word.charAt(0)` you should retrieve the value once and store it in variable.

---

The `Trie`'s `getRoot()` method does not need to check `isEmpty()` and also the `isEmpty()` method is not implemented correctly, because it won't ever return `false` because `root` is final and will be set in the constructor and can't be changed afeterwards ( setting to `null`).

So a better approach would be to check inside the `isEmpty()` method if any word had been added like

```
public boolean isEmpty () {
    return !root.getTerminal();
}
```

whereas I would suggest to extract magical numbers like this to meaningful constants.

---

Comments should describe **why** something is done. Let the code speak for itself about **what** is done by using meaningful and descriptive names for classes, methods and variables.

Comments like

```
// If the child does not exist, return false
if (!childExists(index)) {
    return false;
}
```

are superfluous, because they don't add any value to the code.

---

The test client has some flaws which should be mentioned here too.

Assume a user will enter `S` for searching for a word but doesn't add anything else. Your application would exit with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You need to check for `tokens.length()` before you access `tokens[1]`.

---

Comment: Thanks for the great input! I have corrected the constructor in my code (not edited on post), the "27" letters was a typo :P

I was having some problems with my insert method; where if the last return statement was set to false, the method was always returning false, even if it had correctly inserted the word. I haven't figured out how to correct that yet.
I also corrected the word.charAt(0) problem prior to your post (Updated in code here).

Comment: For what case should the `insert()` method return `false` ?

Comment: Well, none really. The isPresent() method checks the structure before insert() is even called. So, if there were a case that would cause it to return false, it would never be called in the first place. A constraint not mentioned above was that the insert, isPresent, and delete methods must contain the return type and signature listed above.

Comment: I just adjusted my code to account for 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException', I also removed superfluous commenting, and finally adjusted the isEmpty() method in my Trie class. :) Thank you for your great feedback

Comment: Quick question for you... I opted to use getters/setters to not expose the data of the class, but felt that they really could have been omitted. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: I would always use them.

Comment: I did find a bug in my code. It is the delete method in the Node class. If I insert the word "hazardous" and then insert "hazardously", then delete "hazardously" I should be removing the "ly" suffix. However, the method only removes the "y", leaving "hazardousl"